# ORA-00903: invalid table name when Creating Table

Tags: oracle

Please help. I'm not sure what is happening. I even tried to drop table but still unsuccessful.

```
CREATE TABLE 'customer' (
  'customer_id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'type' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  'name' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  'cut_off' int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('customer_id')
)


Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE TABLE 'customer' (
  'customer_id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'type' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  'name' varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  'cut_off' tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('customer_id')
)
```

```
Error report -
ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Table and column names should be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar ... or maybe even _without_ double quotes, in case the table name be not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not an Oracle user, but I know there are times when double quotes are needed even when it's not a reserved word. I think it has to do with upper and lower case.

Comment: @Barmer you use double quotes to make the table name case sensitive, it also allows you to defy other table naming rules. Every time you reference the table you’d need to use double quotes with exactly the same case sensitive name. It’s generally best avoided. By default, without double quotes, the table name will be stored in upper case and can be referred to case insensitively (so long as you don’t use double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Column and table names should be without quotes.

Refer to create table query https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11004

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.

- Names of table and columns should not be wrapped in single quotes.
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` keyword is not allowed. It should be implemented differently in oracle.
- `NOT NULL` is not needed on PK column. It is implicit.

Corrected code:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id int GENERATED always as IDENTITY,
  type varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  cut_off int NOT NULL,
  primary key(customer_id)
);
```